# Spark SQL: How to reduce one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe/table:

```
id|counter
23534074|1
23534074|2
23534074|3
24142005|1
24142005|2
```

and I would like to reduce it to just have distinct ids (e.g. by taking the 1st id row). So, the resulting dataframe should look like:

```
id|counter
23534074|1
24142005|1
```

**This is what I have done so far:**

I read the data with:

```
val tf = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .load("test.csv")
```

create a tempTable with

```
tf.registerTempTable("TF")
```

This is how I try to get a distinct on "id"

```
sqlContext.sql("select distinct(id),counter from TF group by id,counter").show
```

but it doesn't give me the expected result:

```
+--------+-------+
|      id|counter|
+--------+-------+
|23534074|      1|
|23534074|      2|
|23534074|      3|
|24142005|      1|
|24142005|      2|
+--------+-------+
```

Any ideas how to do this using Spark SQL?
Thanks!

Comment: You want to perform a group by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what are your requirements so here are a few options:

- simple filter over `counter` column, this assumes counter is unique and 1 is the value you want

  ```scala
  tf.where($"counter" === 1)
  ```

  equivalent to:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM tf WHERE counter = 1
  ```
- using `groupBy` with first (there is no order guarantee here, what you get is just a first encountered value):

  ```scala
  tf.groupBy($"id").agg(first($"counter")).show
  ```

  equivalent to:

  ```
  SELECT id, FIRST(counter) AS counter FROM tf GROUP BY id
  ```
- window functions, this is useful when counter provides some ordering and you want the lowest / the highest value

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rowNumber

  val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"counter")
  tf.withColumn("rn", rowNumber.over(w)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn")
  ```

  equivalent to

  ```
  SELECT id, counter FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY counter) rn FROM tf
  ) tmp WHERE rn = 1
  ```

Comment: Thanks, @zero323! Good overview of possible options. The "first" did it in my case!